# Implementing the iPhone alpha navigation in the browser

Tags: design-patterns, iphone, help

Curious if anyone has examples of the alpha navigation used in iPhone apps to jump quickly through long lists, but implemented in the browser? Think - a mobile browser version of Contacts.app where you can jump quickly to Smith by tapping the "S" in the alpha list at the right.

Comment: I've seen this in one of Google's labs products, but I can't remember which one... anyone know?

Comment: I found one example on m.linkedin.com. After you get through their login captcha, hit your Contacts list. Its not very user friendly though. It works with a touch but you can't slide on it so it loses the fluidity that makes it useful on the app side.

Comment: Try asking this question in StackOverflow...

Comment: http://devgrow.com/slidernav/